# Programmatically setting TextView backgroundcolor in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am trying to set a simple backgroundcolor of a textview (lblTb1Head) which is part of a **expandablelistview in a fragment**.
Unfortunately I always get a nullpointerexception on *below line* and i cannot find the reason why?

Downvoters, pls be gentle, it`s been a long night for me, maybe too long.

```
txtGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8EBED"));
```

Declaration of txtGroup:

```
public class Tb1_KltGegevens extends Fragment {

    private View v, mProgressView;
    private TextView txtGroup;
...
}
```

My fragments onCreateView:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tb1_kltgegevens, container, false);
        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.expListViewTb1);
        txtGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblTb1Head);

        SharedPreferences settings1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newTheme = settings1.getInt("themeCustom", 0);

        if (newTheme == THEME_LIGHT) {
            txtGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8EBED"));
        }

        return v;
    }
```

My layout file for tb1_kltgegevens:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expListViewTb1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

The *tb1_group.xml* with the textview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTb1Head"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK. Where is `txtGroup` declared as TextView in your Java code? Side note: `fill_parent` has been deprecated in 2010 (with Froyo). Now there's `match_parent`.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, I put the declaration of txtGroup in my question. Thx for the hint of match_parent.

Comment: Can you post the layout file `tb1_kltgegevens.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your TextView `lblTb1Head` is in the Layout `tb1_group.xml`, then you should be inflating the layout view as:

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tb1_group, container, false);
```

Do this and then `txtGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblTb1Head);` won't return null.

Comment: ok thx, no nullpointer anymore but now the expandablelistview does not show anything except the applied color.

Comment: Your question is answered (setBackgroundColor resulting in NPE), and the answer should be accepted. If you have another question, feel free to ask another one.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi, you are right. Think it is time to sleep, tomorrow is another day.